# Need a specific .htaccess regex replacement

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I cannot find the required regex command in order to do the following:

(1) Search a URL for a specific string (substring of a filename), i.e:

url.com/state/**city**_someotherdata.php

OR 
 url.com/state/someotherdata_**city**_xy.php and other variants of this format;

(2) convert the URL into this format:

url.com/state/**city**/index.php

What can be done to do this? I have tried this code

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^\/?]+)\bozeman(?:\?|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^http:\/\/url.com/montana/bozeman/? [L,R=301]
```

without success. This data is going into an .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to get something either before or after an underscore? That's not going to work. This isn't a programming language, you'll want to use a routing engine of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^state\/([^/]*)([^/]*|$) /state/$1_someotherdata.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. Say I load a file named url.com/montana/bozeman_whatever.php, I need this to redirect to url.com/montana/bozeman/index.php, where bozeman is the variable string being searched for in the URL (I'll just make new lines for each city). The city will not always be the first word, I need the regex to search the entire URL.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you are working with Bozeman, Montana. This will do exactly what you need.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(\/montana\/bozeman\/index.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(bozeman).*$
RewriteRule ^ /montana/bozeman/index.php [L,R=302,NE]
</IfModule>
```

You have to use a rewrite condition to exclude the URL you are redirecting to, otherwise the city name (Bozeman in this example) being the same as the folder being directed to, will cause an endless loop.